# About the dual sheaf of an invertible sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Recently I am quite confused about invertible sheaves while reading Hartshorne.

In Chapter 2, exercise 5.1, it is discussed that for a locally free $O_X$-module of finite rank, denoted by $\mathcal{F}$, double dual of $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$ itself. But since $F$ locally looks like the sheaf of modules associated to ${{(Spec\space A)}}^n$(Sorry that I can't type that notation "~"). Don't we have that dual of $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$ itself?

Another question related to this is exercise 5.7(3), again I tried to consider locally, and it seems that I can actually take $\mathcal{G}$ arbitrarily as long as it is also invertible. But after I searched on the Internet, I found that many answer said that I have to choose $\mathcal{G}$ to be the dual of $\mathcal{F}$. I guess I have formed a wrong understanding about sheaves of modules.  It would be kind if you could offer some examples to let me know where I wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A vector space is NOT canonically isomorphic to its own dual (it requires a choice of basis) but it is canonically isomorphic to its double dual. So one cannot expect a vector bundle to be isomorphic to its dual because one cannot choose a basis globally. Could you include the description of exercise 5.7(3) in your questions? Otherwise it is hard to help you with it.

Comment: You're mixing up "locally isomorphic" and "globally isomorphic." Invertible sheaves and their duals are both locally free of rank $1$ hence locally isomorphic to $\mathcal O_X$. For 5.7(c), the point is that you need a global section that can be mapped to $1 \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)$. Given some section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$, you need to multiply it by something to make it $1$, i.e. multiply it by $1/s$, which is a section of $\mathcal F^\vee$.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for your reply, so you mean that I cannot glue these local duals together into a global one? But I am a bit confused for the case $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free of rank one. Since now defining a morphism from $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is the same as defining the image of 1 on U, therefore in this case giving the dual of $F$ is the same as choosing a section of ${O_X}|_U$ on U that can be glued into a global one. So I think for bundles of rank 1, the dual of $F$ is isomorphic to $F$ itself. Is this argument right?@Tabes

Comment: @user45878 Oh thanks a lot, I believe I should write down these dual and double dual to see whether they can be glued together.